# Google Translate API v2 - skip words and special character

Tags: php, google-translate, url-encoding

I'm trying to use the [Google API V2](https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/quickstart#before-you-begin) with PHP

I need to exclude some words so I'm wrapping them into `<span class"notranslate">WORD</span>`

The problem is that my text contains some special chars so I'm using `urlencode($input)`

The issue is that `urlencode` breaks the exclude word functionality ...

What I'm doing wrong ?

**Example**

```
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2";
$params = array(
    'key' => $helper->getConfigValue('google_api'),
    'source' => $from,
    'target' => $to, // NOTE for CHINESE zh-CN
    'q' => urlencode($input),
);
$url .= '?' . http_build_query($params);

$handle = curl_init($url);
....
```

Comment: http_build_query already applies url encoding, so the `urlencode($input)` is redundant.

Comment: I think you are right :) add it as answer I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http_build_query already applies url encoding, so the `urlencode($input)` is redundant

```
<?php
$str = '<span class="notranslate">WORD</span>';

$params = [
    'single' => $str,
    'double' => urlencode($str)
];           
echo http_build_query($params);
```

Results in:

```
single=%3Cspan+class%3D%22notranslate%22%3EWORD%3C%2Fspan%3E
double=%253Cspan%2Bclass%253D%2522notranslate%2522%253EWORD%253C%252Fspan%253E
```

Note the double encoding on `double`.