# Using Google Translate API in Python, how do you indicate that some text is not to be translated?

Tags: python, translate

Using Google Translate API in Python, how do you indicate that some text is not to be translated? The text I have includes variable names e.g. `$name$` that should be left as is. I've tried wrapping these in quotes and angled brackets, but no success so far.

Comment: did you try `<span class="notranslate">$name$</span>`?

Comment: Thanks to both responses (and apologies for my slow reply - it's an occasional hobby project), but I'm using python API, so don't think these apply. 

The snippet of script doing the translation is:
t = service.translations().list(source=base, target=targ, format='text', q=[text]).execute()
where text is something like:
'Here is my $code$ text'
I've tried wrapping the $code$ bit in its own quotes as
'Here is my "$code" text'
and also as
'Here is my <span class="notranslate">$code$</span> text'
but no joy so far.

Comment: The latter is what i had hoped would apply. Oh, have you tried `service.translations().list(source=base, target=targ, format='html', q='Here is my <span class="notranslate">$code$</span>)`? (disclaimer, I have zero clue what valid formats are)

Answer (score 0):

I just found something:

```
This contains <span class="notranslate">$code$</span>, which will be skipped.
```

Related:

- [How can I tell Google Translate to not translate a section of a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628507/how-can-i-tell-google-translate-to-not-translate-a-section-of-a-website)
- [Google Translate API v2 - skip words and special character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690723/google-translate-api-v2-skip-words-and-special-character)